# Hyperref using the wrong language script for \url?

Tags: hyperref, verbatim, urls, polyglossia

In a mixed language document, I try to use a URL. Here is minimal input
demonstrating

```
\documentclass{article} % compile with xelatex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
  \setmainlanguage{hebrew} 
  \setotherlanguage{english}
  \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}% or{SBL Hebrew}
\begin{document}
  \begin{english}English separates Yankees and Brits?
  \url{http://www.google.com}
  \end{english}
\end{document}
```

Now, polyglosssia does not like this at all, complaining that:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: 
The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \url{http://www.google.com}
```

I am confused. Didn't I switch to English on line 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you change your link to  `\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}` instead of using `\url` it works fine.

However, this doesn't actually solve the problem directly.  Building on Leo's answer, but using `polyglossia` methods, (and LaTeX syntax) the correct solution is the following:

```
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\ttfamilylatin}
```

Comment: But we cannot use `\url{http://foo.bar/%12%34%56#7890}` then.

Comment: @Leo I've updated my answer based on yours.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem with \verb+XXX+, which produces the same error message? Perhaps it is the case as @Ulrike suggested, namely a bug with polyglossia font changing algorithm?

Comment: @Yossi: It is a problem of `polyglossia`. You can redefine `\ttfamily` or internal macro `\verbatim@font` to fix the bug.

Answer (score 8):

It has nothing to do with hyperref. `\url` uses `\ttfamily` as font. You get the same message if you simply call `\ttfamily`. At my opinion this is a bug in the font switching system of polyglossia. The script=hebrew option is still present after a language switch.

Comment: Not so sure. I got the same problem with using just old plain \verb+http://www.google.com+

Comment: +1. I agree that it is a problem of `polyglossia`. `english` envrionment does not affect `\ttfamily` here. For verbatim text, you can redefine `\ttfamily` to `\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont` or something similar **after** `document` environment, if typewriter typeface is not required in Hebrew text. This would also solve the problem of `\url`.

Comment: The typewriter typeface is used primarily to demonstrate computer input. Not so common to write instructional material in languages other than English, but it does occur.

Comment: @Yossi. Naturally you get the same problem with `\verb`: it use the typewriter font too. You get the error also if you use `\sffamily`. One could perhaps get around it by setting some fonts explicitly. But whatever polyglossia is doing here, it is at my opinion not sane and should be revised.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug of `url` package. `\url` use `\ttfamily` by default, however, the default typewriter font `lmtt` is not for the default language Hebrew. Just redefine `\UrlFont` to fix it.

```
\def\UrlFont{\usefont{EU1}{lmtt}{m}{n}}
```

Comment: @Yossi I changed my answer to reflect this, but using `polyglossia` methods.  It provides a `\ttfamilylatin` command for this purpose.